# Component is not being styled according to className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For some reason setting `className` is not styling my property:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className={styles.example}>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  example: {
    background: 'black',
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px'
  }
})
```

It just renders something like

```
<div class="175">
</div>
```

With no styling information (there is no CSS rule for the ""class"" 175)

Why is it not (as I expect) ending up with a name like `styles__example___2w27N` with CSS rules specified in the browser

```
.styles__example___2w27N {
    background-color: 'black';
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

How do I get my CSS to be applied?

---

If I use `style={styles.example}` (instead of `className`) I actually get [this error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=62&args%5B%5D=):

> The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string.

I would prefer to use `className` though because

- I have specified hover and active styles, does `style` work with those?
- I want to manually add and override some styles inline

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet check this out.

Comment: @Vektor what should I be looking at ?

Comment: @minseong, are you using react-native or react js web?

Comment: `react-native` and `reactJS` are fundamentally similar but they can't be sharing same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `<View>` component instead of the `<div>` component, as that will map the `<View>` component to the native view UI components for each specific platform that you're using (ie: `<div>` for web, android.view for android, etc.) and not the `<div>` element directly.

With that, the `<View>` element and other react-native core components are designed to work with `StyleSheet`. You should be applying your style to the [`style` prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style) which all core components have, and not the `className` prop:

```
<View style={styles.example}>
</View>
```

When the above is viewed on the web, you'll see a `<div>` being used in the source, but on other platforms you'll see other native view UI types being used.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: I just had no idea react and react-native were different things

Comment: @minseong Yeah, they use similar ideas, but mainly the components/elements that you use are different. The core concepts such as state are still the same though

Comment: How come I am able to render `<div>` in react-native in the first place? And render reactJS components from other developers?

Comment: @minseong I personally don't know the specific reason why they allowed it, but when you use `<div>` in react-native it will still work the same as it does in reactjs, but those components built using html elements will only work on the web, and won't work when viewed on an iOS/android device as they won't understand how to handle and render a `<div>` element like the web does.

Answer (score 1):

Stylesheet refers to React Native... are you doing react-js or react native?

Assuming you are doing react-js (because of the div), there is no such thing as stylesheet in react-js...

```js
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className={styles.example}>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  example: {
    background: 'black',
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px'
  }
}
```

I think you copied the code from a react-native document instead of the react-js...

Comment: Now class is `[object Object]`

Comment: are u doing react-native or react-js?

Comment: can you try `style={styles.example}` instead of `className`?

Comment: With `style=` I get "The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string"

Comment: is this react-js or react native?

Comment: turns out it's react-native